# Entire $f$ and $g$ constant if $e^{f(z)}+e^{g(z)}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have entire functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy $e^{f(z)} + e^{g(z)} = 1 $ for all complex values $z$.  Show that $f$ and $g$ are constant.

Comment: What tools have you to work with? Are you a beginner, or advanced?

Comment: I familiar with one semester of graduate complex analysis. I've tried looking at properties after differentiating this equation. And I've tried taking a look at the at what happens at infinity.

Answer (score 15):

I take it

> one semester of graduate complex analysis

means you have heard of Picard's so-called "little" theorem.

The functions $e^{f(z)}$ and $e^{g(z)}$ are entire, and omit two values, hence they are constant. That immediately implies that $f$ and $g$ are constant.

Comment: Hey that's slick, I even thought about using that but then missed the fact that each can't take value 1.  Thanks for your help!