# Linear dependence of entire functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Given two entire function *f* and *g*, suppose exp(*f*) , exp(*g*) and 1 are linearly dependent in the complex field, how can we show that *f*, *g*, and 1 are also linearly dependent ?

Comment: It might help to start from the definitions of of entire function and linear dependence.

Comment: @Math1000 How does the definition work? I tried to use wronskian, but seemed useless.

Comment: Well, what does it mean for a set of functions to be linearly dependent?

Comment: @Math1000 Actually, I know the definition of those two terms, but I can’t figure out how it works in the problem. I am not sure how to use the exp to generate f and g.

Comment: Do you know Picard's (little) theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah... It’s about the value of non constant entire function.  So, what should I do next ?

Comment: You can reduce it to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626363/entire-f-and-g-constant-if-efzegz-1) or a simpler situation.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I think I can deal with it now.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hi! It’s me again. Through your hint, I have already solved the posted problem. However, I wonder if it is true for arbitrary many entire functions. I tried the same trick by using Picard Thm, but it is not easy as the case of n=2 in this post. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, for an arbitrary number of functions you cannot conclude that each of the functions is constant. Perhaps from $\sum_{k = 1}^n \exp f_k(z) \equiv 1$ one can conclude that at least one of the $f_k$ is constant, and that of course gives the linear dependence of $1, f_1, \ldots, f_n$. But I don't see how one could prove (or refute) that now.